# What benefits does the % formatter offer in comparison to f strings?

Tags: python, f-string

I was going through the fluent python book when I came across the following code

```py
def tag(name, *content, cls=None, **attrs):
    """Generate one or more HTML tags"""
    if cls is not None:
        attrs['class'] = cls
    if attrs:
        attr_str = ''.join(' %s="%s"' % (attr, value)
    for attr, value
        in sorted(attrs.items()))
    else:
        attr_str = ''
    if content:
        return '\n'.join('<%s%s>%s</%s>' %
                         (name, attr_str, c, name) for c in content)
    else:
        return f'<{name}{attr_str} />'
```

Since this book was introduced prior to f-strings, I thought I could make the following replacement

```py
    if content:
        return '\n'.join(f'<{name}{attr_str}>{[c for c in content]}<{name}>')
```

This returns each character on a new line. Rather than the desired output: `'<p>hello</p>'`

Is the % formater necessary here? Can this output be achieved using a list comprehension?

Comment: you can use `f'<{name}{attr_str}>{c}</{name}>'` instead of `'<%s%s>%s</%s>'` and probably this should works `"\n".join( f'<{name}{attr_str}>{c}<{name}>' for c in content )`

Comment: This works! Just so I can ensure my understanding, this is a generator expression, correct? The logic is as follows: Create a new line, after finishing each iteration of the expression `(f'<...>' for c in content)`. Where one iteration is "complete" after each argument is passed? I feel like I am missing a fundamental concept of generator expressions, as I always get back generator objects rather than my desired result.

Comment: in both versions you have generator which create many elements and `join()` use them like list to concatenate elemenets from list. You can use `[ ]` to create list comprehension `data = [ f'<{name}{attr_str}>{c}<{name}>' for c in content ]` and see what you get in list - `print(data)`

Comment: That's super interesting `return '\n'.join([f'<{name}{attr_str}>{c}<{name}>' for c in content])` gives back the desired result.  So I suppose, moving the list comprehension into the f-string provides single characters to the `'\n'.join...` argument whereas using it outside the f-string provides each list item as input to the `'\n'.join...` argument. Is there any particular reason to go with a generator vs a list object in this specific context?

Comment: list comprehension has to create full list before `join()` will use it - so it may need more memory then generator. But list comprehension can be useful when you have to use the same list two times - like in my answer I print this list and later use in `join()` so I don't have to generate the same list two times so I use less time. But for small number of elements you will no see that you use more memory or more time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
'<%s%s>%s</%s>' % (name, attr_str, c, name)
```

you can use

```
f'<{name}{attr_str}>{c}</{name}>'
```

so finally you will have generator

```
f'<{name}{attr_str}>{c}<{name}>' for c in content
```

instead of

```
'<%s%s>%s</%s>' % (name, attr_str, c, name) for c in content
```

and

```
return '\n'.join( f'<{name}{attr_str}>{c}<{name}>' for c in content )
```

---

You can also use `[]` to create list comprehension and use `print()` to see all created elements before it uses them in `join()`

```
data = [ f'<{name}{attr_str}>{c}<{name}>' for c in content ]
print(data)
return "\n".join( data )
```